# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh maxiter doing nothing

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue, lanczos

```
eig_valsh, eig_vectorsh = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=18, which = 'LM', maxiter = 1)
here
```

I'm finding that as I adjust maxiter nothing happens. It gives the same answer for maxiter = 1 as any other value. I know that the eigenvalues found are incorrect so it is not the case that it is converging in one iteration. Can anyone guide me on what issue this is indicative of? Many thanks.

I was expecting the eigenvalues found to actually change as maxiter was altered, however things remained exactly the same.

Comment: Can you include a value of `A` which triggers this issue, to make this example reproducible?